# Not able to match the first two character of string

Tags: mongodb

i am doing aggregation for mongo data and did unwind and got data. now i want to sort entire data in two sections eg:

```
$unwind {path:”$log”}

log : object1
     TIME : “”
     HOST : “gtcrd-asdfh.nam”
     BACKEND : “”
log : object2
     TIME : “”
     HOST : “swcrd-asdf.nam”
     BACKEND : “”
```

there are huge data of this i want to sort entire data by HOST of first two characters, so that i will get all host either in sw and gt. please help me on this other segregation i did but this sorting thing is not working.

Comment: If you want to filter data by first two characters of a string, use a regex query.

Comment: Also, can you share a sample document from MongoDB

Comment: i tried regex not working, i thought $match will work with regex but not working

Answer (score 0):

This will sort the whole collection by first 2 characters of host value. I dont know if this will fit for you.

[Try it here.](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UT9TziXp6Be)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      TIME: 1,
      BACKEND: 1,
      HOST: 1,
      HOSTTYPE: {
        $substr: [
          "$HOST",
          0,
          2
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      HOSTTYPE: -1
    }
  }
])
```

Hope it helps.